# Chromium browser proxy settings

Tags: internet

My Pi has Raspbian Jessie and it is behind my college's proxy server. I am able connect to the internet and download packages.

I even tried doing export http_proxy=user:pwd@proxy:port

I am not able to access any website using Chromium browser.

Comment: IIRC In the settings menu under settings (under advanced settings) you can configure the proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the proxy settings is in chromium is normally not necessary since they are picked up from the system.

However, assuming you have already rebooted and restarted chromium, and it still is not working. You can configure the proxy settings for Chromium by clicking the menu (three vertical dots to the right of the address bar), and selecting **settings**. Then scroll to the bottom of the page and click **Show advanced settings**. Under the **Network** heading click **Change proxy settings** You can also configure the settings from the command line. Use the following command:

`man chromium-browser`

to get the specifics.

Comment: I am trying to configure using command line. So I typed this, $ chromium-browser --proxy-server="http://proxy:port" Where do I give my user name and password?

Comment: @AbhilashA I would assume right on the commandline

Comment: Firefox picks up the system proxy, but Chromium doesn't. There is no "Change proxy settings" in Chromium 80.0.3987.87, only "Open your computer's proxy settings".

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command in terminal

```
chromium-browser --proxy-server="proxy_ipaddress:port"
```

Example:

**chromium-browser --proxy-server="172.16.2.88:8080"**

Kudos new browser will open with proxy bypass.